# Добавление элементов в JList

Tags: java, swing

Не добавляются элементы массива в `JList`. Выдает ошибки:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at laba2.MyForm.setData(MyForm.java:83)
>       at laba2.lab4.main(lab4.java:19)

Как можно исправить это и все таки вывести элементы `aircraft` в `JList`?

MyForm.java

```
package laba2;
import laba2.ACrafts;
import laba2.List;
import laba2.lab4;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;

public class MyForm {
    JFrame formShow;
    private JList<ACrafts> list;
    private List li;
    private DefaultListModel<ACrafts> lm;
    private DefaultComboBoxModel<String> cm;
    private JComboBox comboBox;
    private JButton btnAdd;
    private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel tableMOdel;


    private void MyForm() {


        formShow = new JFrame("Aircrafts");
        formShow.setBounds(100, 100, 579, 451);
        formShow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        formShow.setLayout(null);

        lm = new DefaultListModel<ACrafts>();
        cm = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();

        li = new List();
        ACrafts[] arr;
        arr = li.toArray();


        list = new JList<ACrafts>(lm);
        for(ACrafts a: li){
            lm.addElement(a);
        }
        list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        list.setLocation(30, 95);
        list.setSize(245, 150);


        formShow.add(list);


        btnAdd = new JButton("add");
        btnAdd.setBounds(375, 150, 100, 50);
        formShow.add(btnAdd);

        JFrame formAdd = new JFrame("Add and remove");
        formAdd.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        formAdd.setBounds(100, 100, 579, 451);

        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                formShow.setVisible(false);
                formAdd.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
    public void setData(ACrafts a) {
        li.add(a);

    }       
}
```

lab4.java

```
package laba2;

import laba2.MyForm;

public class lab4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ACrafts[] aircraft = new ACrafts[5];

        aircraft[0] = new ACrafts("Boeing 767-300F","США",7130,54000,13100,850);
        aircraft[1] = new ACrafts("Airbus 310-300F","Франция",39000,9600,12200,850);
        aircraft[2] = new ACrafts("Boeing 757-200F","США",7100,39780,12500,935);
        aircraft[3] = new ACrafts("IL-86","Украина",3300,15000,11000,950);
        aircraft[4] = new ACrafts("Avro RJ-100","Великобритания",2255,9500,10600,890);

        MyForm form = new MyForm();

        form.setData(aircraft[0]);
        form.setData(aircraft[1]);
        form.setData(aircraft[2]);
        form.setData(aircraft[3]);
        form.setData(aircraft[4]);

        form.formShow.setVisible(true);



    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут проблема в сигнатуре вашего якобы конструктора

```
private void MyForm()
```

у вас это приват метод в Java. А вы используете `new MyForm()` и тем самым вызовете конструктор по умолчанию где все ваши переменные ещё `null`. Ведь он у вас не определен. Уберите `private void` в вашей форме и он станет конструктором и будет счастье.

Если вы хотели использовать паттерн синглтон(это когда единственный конструктор приватный), то там используется другой подход.

И не добавляйте элементы сразу на фрейм юзайте JPanel и добавляйте его на `getContentPane()`.

Comment: Да, теперь окно запустилось!) Но элементы массива по прежнему не выводятся. Просто пустой JList. (все элементы окна добавляю на jpanel)

Comment: оно и понятно вы элемент в List li добавляете, а не в DefaultListModel lm. используйте  `public void setData(ACrafts a) {
       lm.addElement(a);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Вы коллекцию считываете в конструкторе формы, а заполняет её потом при этом модель не обновляете.

Comment: ругается именно на метод setData(), как в мейне, так и в классе myForm. Почему? Что не так?